# Deleting row from database and arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-alertdialog

This is what I have done till now;

Activity Class;

```
traineesListView
            .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View arg1, int arg2, final long person_id) {
                    currentTrainee = (Trainee) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(
                            arg2);
                    SharedMemory.getInstance().setCurrentTrainee(
                            currentTrainee);

                    String items[] = { "Edit your information",
                            "Unregister from training" };
                    Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            TraineeActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Dear!" + " "
                            + currentTrainee.getFormatedName() + "," + " "
                            + "Choose your action!!");
                    alert.setItems(items, new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                int selectedItem) {

                            if (selectedItem == 0) {

                                SharedMemory.getInstance()
                                        .setCurrentAction(
                                                SharedMemory.ACTION_EDIT);
                                SharedMemory.getInstance()
                                        .setCurrentTrainee(currentTrainee);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        TraineeActivity.this,
                                        FormActivity.class);
                                TraineeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            } else if (selectedItem == 1) {
                                // delete trainee information
                                Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        TraineeActivity.this);
                                alert.setTitle("Dear!" + " "
                                        + currentTrainee.getFormatedName());
                                alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to unregister from training?");
                                alert.setPositiveButton(
                                        "YES",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface arg0,
                                                    int arg1) {
                                                int training_id = SharedMemory
                                                        .getInstance()
                                                        .getCurrentTraining()
                                                        .getId();
                                                // Unregister Trainee
                                                currentTrainee
                                                        .unRegisterFromTraining(training_id);
                                                Log.i( "Training ID:"+Integer.toString(training_id), "Person ID:"+Integer.toString(currentTrainee.getId()));
                                                // Remove trainee from
                                                // ArrayList
                                            }
                                        });

                                alert.setNegativeButton(
                                        "NO",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(
                                                    DialogInterface arg0,
                                                    int arg1) {
                                                arg0.cancel();

                                            }
                                        });
                                alert.show();

                            }

                        }

                    });
                    alert.show();
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

My model class:

```
public void unRegisterFromTraining(int training_id) {

    DatabaseHelper db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();

    db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ATTENDANCE, DatabaseHelper.TrainingId
            + "=" + training_id + "AND" + DatabaseHelper.PersonId+"= ?"
            ,new String[] {Integer.toString(this.getId())});

}
```

My database class;

```
public void delete(String tableAttendance, String where,String[] whereArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I am not able to remove the row from db table, and even I cannot see any errors. I need some way. It might be simple for you but I could not figure out why? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: you may need some spaces around your `"AND"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void delete(String tableAttendance, String where,String[] whereArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This method implementation is empty and it does nothing. You should probably delegate it to the `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
public void delete(String tableAttendance, String where,String[] whereArgs) {
    db.delete(tableAttendance, where, whereArgs);
}
```

where `db` is an open-for-writing `SQLiteDatabase` member.

After that fix the SQL syntax:

```
db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ATTENDANCE, DatabaseHelper.TrainingId
        + "=" + training_id + "AND" + DatabaseHelper.PersonId+"= ?"
        ,new String[] {Integer.toString(this.getId())});
```

You need whitespace around the `AND`.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "1ANDperson_id" (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM attendance WHERE training_id=1ANDperson_id= ?

Get this error!!!

Comment: Yes, you need to change `"AND"` to `" AND "` to add whitespace around it.

Comment: Works like a charm.. :). Simple mistake makes headache sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You may go wrong over here. Provide space between `AND`  and provide `"=?"` instead of single `"="` after Parameter passed. Corrected below

```
 db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_ATTENDANCE, DatabaseHelper.TrainingId
    + "= ?" + training_id + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.PersonId+"= ?"
    ,new String[] {Integer.toString(this.getId())});
```

Comment: then @user3180746 post your logcat in brief